# How to inject data class using Koin?

Tags: android, dependency-injection, koin

When my application starts I create object with some data and I want to share the same instance of object between services/viewModels.

Is it possible to inject the same instance of data class to viewModel using Koin?

Edit:
I create user object in `MainViewModel` when app loaded data from firebase at start.

```
@IgnoreExtraProperties
@Keep
data class User(
    val id: String = "",
    val name: String? = null,
    val surname: String? = null,
    val email: String? = null,
    val avatarUrl: String? = null
)
```

Comment: Yes it is. How is the data class instance created and which component owns it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your view model inherits from `KoinComponent`, you can access `getKoin` method to declare your user object.

```kotlin
class MainViewModel : ViewModel(), KoinComponent {
```

The user object will be available to rest of your application after declaration.

```kotlin
// user created from data from firebase ...

fun insertKoinFor(user: User) {
    // declare koin the user of type User
    getKoin().declare<User>(user)

    // or declare with a named qualifier
    getKoin().declare(user, named("myUser"))
}
```

Hope, it helps.

Comment: now how to get the user via koin?

Answer (score 1):

I would create a holder object, say `UserManager`, to hold an optional `User` instance. This holder is something you can provide in your koin graph as `single`, and whatever component responsible setting up the `User` instance (for example your `MainViewModel`) can update the instance inside the singleton holder.